# XNA weird 3D painting when painting text

Tags: c#, xna, sprite, paint

I'm working on a 3D Spaceship game with XNA 3.1

I tried to separate my painting code from the game logic (altought XNA makes this almost).

I'm using a special static class that paints my models on screen... the main Game class uses this code at painting:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        // Draws the stage (the skybox and objects like rocks)
        stageManager.Draw(gameTime, GraphicsDevice, camera);


        // Draws each player and each Enemy on stage given the camera
        foreach (Player p in players)
            p.Draw(camera);

        foreach(Enemy e in enemies)
            e.Draw(camera);

        if(Configuration.Debug)
            col.renderColBoundings(GraphicsDevice, camera);

        GraphicHelper.drawOverlayText("50", "10"); // "Error" line...

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

But when I paint text, something weird occurs... Here's an image ([original](http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/1371/errorspacehogs.png)):
[image]

As you can see, everything looks overlapped (but in place)... Like the spaceship turbines.

The code inside `GraphicHelper.drawOverlayText` is this:

```
public static void drawOverlayText(String p1Hp, String currEnemies)
    {
        string text1 = "Player1: " + p1Hp;
        string text2 = "Enemies: " + currEnemies + "/10";
        string text3 = "Space Hogs Beta";

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        // Draw the string twice to create a drop shadow, first colored black
        // and offset one pixel to the bottom right, then again in white at the
        // intended position. This makes text easier to read over the background.
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text1, new Vector2(651, 11), Color.Gray);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text1, new Vector2(650, 10), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text2, new Vector2(851, 11), Color.Gray);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text2, new Vector2(850, 10), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text3, new Vector2(741, 611), Color.Gray);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, text3, new Vector2(740, 610), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

And this static class has this attributes:

```
static ContentManager content;
    static GraphicsDevice graphics;
    static Camera camera;
    static Dictionary<String, Model> models = new Dictionary<string, Model>();
    static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    static SpriteFont font;

    public static void initHelper(ContentManager c, GraphicsDevice g, Camera cam)
    {
        content = c;
        graphics = g;
        camera = cam;
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(g);
        font = c.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts/main");
    }
```

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The odd rendering you are seeing is because the depth buffer is turned off. It gets turned off when you use SpriteBatch. This is a known oddity of the XNA 3.1 API. XNA 4.0 at least makes it a bit more obvious that this is happening.

[Here is an explanation of what render states are changed by SpriteBatch in XNA 3.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924160345/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2006/11/13/spritebatch-and-renderstates.aspx). And [here is the same thing for XNA 4.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112225515/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx).

The solution is to basically set your render states back to what you want them to be, after using SpriteBatch. In this case, at least, set:

```
GraphicsDevice.RenderState.DepthBufferEnable = true;
```

(There may also be some other states in there you want to change back.)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that did it! I knew it was something to do with the  graphics device but not exactly what :P